# How to Update a table using transaction log row by row using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic-sql

I have a table which shows Ticket ID and its status and who is assigned to on a BI Database. Here No duplicates and granularity is each ticket.

Ticket Table

```
Ticket_ID   Status  Assigned_To   Date
001         Open    Team A        01/01/2020 10:01
002         Working Team B        01/01/2020 10:01
003         Open    TeamC         02/01/2020 18:50
004         ResolvedTeam B        02/01/2020 19:22
```

Now, there is a daily transaction log containing each change. However, Field Changes are appearing as Rows as below.

Daily Trasaction logs

```
Ticket_id       Field_Name      New Value      Date
001           Assigned_to       Team B        02/01/2020 10:23
002           Assigned_to       Team A        02/01/2020 10:23
002           Status            Resolved      02/01/2020 10:24
003           status            Resolved      03/01/2020 10:24
004           Assigned_to       Team C        03/01/2020 13:50
004           Assigned_to       Team A        03/01/2020 13:51
004           Status            Resolved      03/01/2020 13:51
```

Now I want to write an update script to update the Ticket table based on the new values on the logs. Considering daily transaction Log table is  created every day I was thinking set operation will not work. I need SQL script to go row by row on Transaction log table and update the Ticket table with New Values. I know this is inefficient, however, number of rows are just hundreds per day. Not thousands.

The results i would like to see is as below where ticket table is updated with latest values..

```css
Ticket_ID       Status     Assigned_To  Date
001           Open       Team B       02/01/2020 10:23
002           Resolved   Team A       02/01/2020 10:24
003           Resolved   TeamC        03/01/2020 10:24
004           Resolved   Team A       03/01/2020 13:51
```

Can someone help me. thank you

Comment: is it possible you have 2 status updates on the same day? Or a ticket assigned to "Team A" and then reasigned to "Team B"  on a same day?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But I have datetime stamp therefore, we cannot have two assignments in same time. I updated the log table

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the most recent change for each column using `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (ticket_id, field_name) dtl.*
from daily_transaction_logs dtl
order by ticket_id, date desc;
```

You can then aggregate this to get one row per ticket:

```
select ticket_id,
       max(new_value) filter (where field_name = 'Assigned_to') as assigned_to,
       max(new_value) filter (where field_name = 'Status') as status,
       max(date) as date
from (select distinct on (ticket_id, field_name) dtl.*
      from daily_transaction_logs dtl
      order by ticket_id, date desc
     ) tf
group by ticket_id;
```

Finally, you can incorporate this into an update:

```
update tickets t
    set assigned_to = tt.assigned_to,
        status = tt.status,
        date = tt.date
    from (select ticket_id,
                 max(new_value) filter (where field_name = 'Assigned_to') as assigned_to,
                 max(new_value) filter (where field_name = 'Status') as status,
                 max(date) as date
          from (select distinct on (ticket_id, field_name) dtl.*
                from daily_transaction_logs dtl
                order by ticket_id, date desc
               ) tf
          group by ticket_id
         ) tt
    where tt.ticket_id = t.ticket_id;
```

Comment: I came up with the same answer so I won't dublicate it. Adding a link to [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=04395b0fcfd7c796ec9787243f87feee). One difference - you should add coalesce to your update because some fields may not be changed (for example field assigned_to for ticket 003).

Comment: Thank you Both Julius Tuskenis and Gordon. But this is not Microsoft SQL?? Its not working  for me. When I run the first part of Gordon's script it says "Incorrect Syntax near the Keyword On"

Comment: @DataMan . . . No.  This is Postgres, just as the question is tagged.

Comment: Thank you everyone. In MS SQL I created a CTE to get the table updated. If anyone needed I can share the code. But the logic is really helpful. Thank you

Comment: @DataMan . . . If you have a SQL Server question, ask a *new* question.  The approach would be rather different and this question has been answered.